# Form data not saved in localstorage except I refresh the browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a form. The aim is to save the form data to localStorage, and also populate the form fields with the data in the localStorage.

After submitting the form, data do not save to localStorage except I refresh the browser.

Even after I refresh and I see the data in localStorage, I open a new browser, launch the form. I check the localStorage but, the data do not show.

I will appreciate your advice.

Thank you

After submitting the form
[image]

After reloading the page
[image]

**HTML Code**

```html
<form action="https://formspree.io/f/xwkaygyj" method="POST">
       <div class="name">
         <input id="name" type="text" name="name" required        placeholder="Name" oninput="onChangeHandler(this)"/>
       <input id="email" type="email" name="email" required placeholder="example@gmail.com" oninput="onChangeHandler(this)"/>
      <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="30" rows="7" maxlength="500" placeholder="Write your message here" required oninput="onChangeHandler(this)">
       </textarea>
                
     <button type="submit">Send</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript Code**

```js
const formName = document.getElementById('name');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const message = document.getElementById('message');


let formData = { name: '', email: '', message: '' };

const onChangeHandler = (event) => {
  switch (event.name) {
    case 'name':
      formData = { ...formData, name: event.value };
      break;
    case 'email':
      formData = { ...formData, email: event.value };
      break;
    case 'message':
      formData = { ...formData, message: event.value };
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(formData));
};
const reloadBrowser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('data'));
if (reloadBrowser) {
  formName.value = reloadBrowser.name;
  email.value = reloadBrowser.email;
  message.value = reloadBrowser.message;
}
```

Comment: i tried in jsfiddle and its working i dont see any problem
https://jsfiddle.net/amirrahman132132/netqf59u/

Comment: THE  form will work fine with the `localStorge`. on every change with the inputs, will be saved on the `localStorage` as `name`, `email` and `message`.
The problem was caused after the form submission. @AmirRahman

Comment: Thanks, @AmirRahman, so is there any workaround after submitting the form?

Comment: You don't have access to another domain with **local storage** only with the same **root**. The **local storage** isn't a backend.

Comment: Great. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use AJAX to efficiently submit your request to server, this is cleaner and less error-prone rather than manually capturing input data through `swtich` statement, furthermore you ascertain the data is successfully submitted to server and a copy is stored in local storage as well.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: $("form").attr("action"),
  data: $("form").serialize(), 
  //Or your custom data
  success: function(response) { 
     localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(formData));
  },
});
```